# How can I fall-through when matching routes in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to deploy the FastAPI app + front end in one Docker container, so I would not want to add NginX or another web server as it'll complicate the setup.

My routes should look like this:

```
/ <-- should serve index.html
/{id} <-- should serve index.html, but only when {id} is int
/css/* <-- should serve files from css directory
/... <-- a few other static files (e.g. /service-worker.js)

/api/<whatever> <-- these are the fastAPI routes
```

So one solution is to match /{id} when it's int and fall-through when it's not. Alternatively if there's a way to just serve everything as static file, except /api calls, that would work too.

Currently I have something like this in my main.py:

```py
@app.get('/api/items')
async def get_items():
    return [{'id':1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id':2, 'name': 'b'}]

@app.get('/{id}')
async def root():
    with open('html/index.html', 'r') as f:
        return HTMLResponse(f.read())

app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="dist"), name="static")
```

But i'm getting 404 when i navigate to "/". I'm serving it with `uvicorn main:app`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with `FastAPI app + front end` ? What kind of front end is it? Is it an app, static files or something else?

Comment: @lsabi it's just an html page with some css/js files

Answer (score 2):

As documented, you need to "mount" a static file path. You can set a folder with the name you like and add a prefix on the URL.

It'll then refresh at every page change, so you'll need some way to store access tokens/session data in the client. Also, every single call will go from the client to the API.

Below the link to the documentation about static files:

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/#static-files